# IntelliJ code collapse doesn't collapse some code

Tags: intellij-idea

for some reason, unlike Eclipse, IntelliJ chooses not to collapse some of the code when i tell it to fold everything.  not sure why this is, or how to force it to collapse everything.  it's pretty annoying.  seems some code just doesn't want to fold.  is there a way to get it to fold everything, rather than just the stuff it feels like collapsing?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure folding to your liking in `Settings → Editor → Code Folding`.
If there is some specific code you want to fold, there's "Fold Code Block" action (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Period</kbd>)

Comment: To add to this, `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Num Pad -` and `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Num Pad +` will collapse and expand all foldable regions in the current file. See more options in the _Code > Folding_ menu.

Answer (score 1):

Surround your code with `editor-fold`tag to make it foldable.

Eg:

```
//<editor-fold desc="Description of folded code">
anything();
void myFunction(){
    foo();
    bar();
}
somefunction();
somethingelse();
//</editor-fold>
```

This entire section can then be folded and only `Description of folded code` will be seen.